# Can't import clojure records

Tags: clojure

I have created a record like this:

```
(defrecord User [user-id email])
```

:but when I try to access it from another name-space I get the error:

```
(User. "name" "email")
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: User

It works when I do:

```
(oe.model.modelcore.User. "name" "email")
```

: I know I will need to import the Java class, but is there any way for clojure to do this automatically when I do:

```
(use 'oe.model.modelcore :reload)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Technically you must require it (don't necessarily need to use it) so that the file containing the record definition is compiled and the class is created.  Then you must import it so that it is available to construct as a Java class.  If you create a constructor function in the first ns like

```
(defn new-user [id email] 
  (User. id email))
```

then you will not need to import it in the calling ns.

I wrote this up a while back here:

- http://tech.puredanger.com/2010/06/30/using-records-from-a-different-namespace-in-clojure/

Comment: Thankfully, that is no more necessary starting with Clojure 1.3, where records became first class citizens. Just wished to leave a comment for people reading this now.

Comment: From my experience you need to AOT compile, and both require and import records. (Of course we were using prismatic's schema library to validate our records)

Answer (score 14):

It could be really tricky if you have `-` (dash) in your name space.

> As it turns out there were two errors:
>
> – Importing defrecord from another namespace is not just :use. I had to first :require the namespace, then import the defrecord. This was a trivial problem to solve and I figured it out quickly. Only this did not work in my case
>
> – Dashes “-” and Underscores “_” are a nuisance since we are mixing Lisp with Java. While the file system uses underscores Clojure converts things to dashes. Brilliant.
>
> So to fix the second error I use the follow in the ns block
>
> ```
> (ns adder.core
>     (:require building-blocks.activity)
>     (:import [building_blocks.activity Activity]))
> ```

https://cyrax.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/clojure-importrequireuse-defrecord-from-another-namespace/

Comment: +1 The underscore issue in the :import is what was still biting me, so thanks for adding this long after the OP accepted an answer.

Comment: Sorry for the downvoting, it is by mistake and I cannot take it back!

Answer (score 12):

In your question you are creating a record, then invoking the constructor for the class generated as a side effect. To do so you need to import that class as mentioned in another answer.

However, imho the preferred path (since Clojure 1.4) is to use the constructor functions generated by defrecord (here they'll be named `->User` and `map->User`). These functions allow you to avoid the interop forms and just refer in the constructor functions like any other function. By avoiding interop, this is a more portable less-hosty solution:

```
(ns some-ns 
  (:require [oe.model.modelcore :refer (->User)]))

(def user (->User "name" "email"))
```

Comment: see also: https://stuartsierra.com/2015/05/17/clojure-record-constructors

Answer (score 11):

You have to import the record like this:

```
(ns some-ns
  (:import [oe.model.modelcore User]))
```

Comment: I changed the accepted answer to this as this was the answer that worked for me in January 2014